# Is topology on topological vector space and topology induced by separating family of seminorms are same?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I had come across the definition of topological vector space also topology induced by separating family of seminorm.

Are both topologies are equivalent?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Many topologies may be defined on a vector space. In general, these are not all equal to a topology induced by seminorms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any separating family of semi-norms induces a topology which makes the space a a locally convex topological vector space. So a non-locally convex topology cannot coincide with the topology generated by a separating family of semi-norms.